# How can I rotateY an element without dipping underneath the page in 3d space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, webkit

I'm attempting to achieve a CSS 3 effect where when you click on an image in a bank of images, it expands to all the available area and flips over at the same time.

The way I was able to accomplish this was to clone the element and absolutely position it on top of the original then transform that. In the code below the cloned image is assigned the classes `clone` and `activated`.

All is well.

However, if I *pre-flip* all of the images in the series of images, activated using the flip all button (adding `origflipped` class, which has rotateY(180deg) so now the *backs* are showing) and then try the same effect (expand and now rotateY(0deg) to the *front* side), the animation somehow has unintended side effects.

It looks like when the rotateY transition is executing, half of the image in the rotation effect dips *below* the page in 3d space, behind the other images and out of view.

So how can I rotateY(0) from rotateY(180deg) without having half of the image floating underneath other things?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var ALL_CARDS = [
    ['http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/26n3ms', 'http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/26n3mr'],
    ['http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/26n3ma', 'http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/26n3mq'],
    ['http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/26n3mb', 'http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/26n3mt'],
    ['http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/26n3mc', 'http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/26n3mu'],
    ['http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/26n3md', 'http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/26n3mv'],
  ];

  var width = 100;

  for (var i = 0; i < ALL_CARDS.length; i++) {

    $(document.createElement('div'))
      .addClass("card")
      .append(
        $('<img src="' + ALL_CARDS[i][0] + '" />')
        .addClass("face front")
      )
      .append(
        $('<img src="' + ALL_CARDS[i][1] + '" />')
        .addClass("face back")
      )
      .width(width)
      .height(width + 10)
      .appendTo($('#target_area'))
      .find('img').width('100%').height('100%');
  }


  $('#target_area .card')
    .click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var original = $(this);
      var proxy = $(this).clone();
      var body = $('body');

      original.addClass("origshown");

      proxy
        .css({
          'position': 'absolute',
          'top': this.offsetTop,
          'left': this.offsetLeft - 5
        })
        .click(function() {
          original.removeClass("origshown");
          $(this).remove();
        })
        .addClass("clone")
        .appendTo($('#target_area'));

      var border_width = 10;

      proxy
        .css({
          'background-color': 'white',
          'top': border_width,
          'left': border_width,
          'height': body.height() - (2 * border_width),
          'width': body.width() - (2 * border_width),
        })
        .addClass('activated');


    });

  $('#flip_all').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.card').toggleClass('origflipped');
  });
});
```

```css
#target_area .face {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

#target_area .face img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

#target_area .face.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#target_area .card {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

#target_area .card.origshown {
  -webkit-transition-property: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#target_area .card.origflipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#target_area .card.clone {
  float: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#target_area .card.clone.activated {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#target_area .card.clone.origflipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#target_area .card.clone.origflipped.activated {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="target_area"></div>
  <input type="button" value="flip all" id="flip_all" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, Testing this works fine for me in chrome 5.0.375.99,
http://jsfiddle.net/Fhxb3/

so im not sure what you issue is, what browser are you using?

also, although im sure you know this, it is completly broken in firefox/ie (but thats cause your using -webkit styles

Comment: I'm trying this on safari 5.0